# How to allocate more than required memory in the stack in C?

Tags: c, memory, stack, allocation

For eg.

```
int x;
```

`x` is allocated 4 bytes of memory. What I want is to allocate more than 4 bytes for `x`, eg. 8. For integers, I can easily use a `long long int` but what about structs?

```
struct Es {
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

I could add a `char useless[<Extra memory>]` but I want to specify how much memory to allocate while allocating. For eg.

```
struct Es es; //I want to specify how much to allocate here
```

And I'm talking about actual allocation, not stack alignment.

It has to be the stack and it has to be specified while allocating.

Comment: Welcome! Can you explain your use case? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: *"Don't ask how I will use it."*, well we kind of have to.  This smells *strongly* of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If your program is mismanaging memory, use a tool like valgrind to find out where.

Comment: @Reid Why exactly do I have to say why I want to do this? I have a specific question and I want the answer. I get that people can suggest alternatives but I not interested in those. I am actually not new to SO, I just got a new Google Account, so I made a new account at SO. And I don't think I have to say why I want to do this. I've never found that anywhere on the help center and I've never had to say that before.

Comment: You can have overallocated structs using `alignas` - by specifying higher alignment, you will force compiler to allocate more memory.

Comment: @dbush this is a legitimate question on it's own. Granted, it is not immediately clear why OP might want this, but it should not be required to answer the question.

Comment: @SmGreatC unfortunately, too often do I see people raising 'XY problem' argument when the question has all the information needed to answer it.

Comment: We're asking because such a thing is **very** unorthodox and may not be possible, and usually when someone asks for something like this it's because they're unaware of other methods that are *much* simpler or robust.

Comment: @dbush Yes it is. That's none of your concern but thank you very much for the advice but in this case an XY problem is suited.

Comment: @SergeyA It's mostly because of 1 rep, people think I'm new to programming and don't know how to ask a question. They are just trying to help out. But I don't need it, that's the problem. I will remove the slight background story at the end. This should fix it.

Comment: Wait, is the amount of memory you want to reserve determined at compile time or runtime? I assumed it was at runtime but I may be misunderstanding

Comment: @dbush it is not that unorthodox, btw. over-allocating is used, for example, to detect out-of-bounds access in controlled builds. And the question does have an answer as asked (see my answer)

Comment: @Addison It's at compile time.

Comment: I will say that a red flag that someone may not know what they are doing is if they get annoyed when asked to explain their reasoning or goals, or fall back on “I’m smart, just trust me”.

Comment: *"It's a deadly function, that deadliness comes from over optimizations"* If a function's behavior changes with optimization, then it almost certainly has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @dbush It's my optimizations, not the compiler's. I just skipped a few checks, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to overallocate memory for structs would be to use alignas macro. Here is an example:

```
 #include <stdalign.h>

 struct Foo { int l; };

 void z(struct Foo );
 void y(int );

 void foo() {
    alignas (512) struct Foo f;
    int k = 20;
    z(f); 
    y(k);
 }
```

You can put that code into online compiler and inspect ASM generated to confirm that `F` is over-allocated.

Comment: Why do I need an online compiler though?

Comment: In my experience, it's easiest way to verify certain assumptions hold true (i.e. how much stack is allocated). You do not have to do this, of course.

Comment: @dbush, yes, it could be used for various purposes. The most common one I seen was to over-allocate objects to 64bytes to prevent false sharing.

Comment: Wait, in which side is it over allocated? I mean, to which side of the actual data is the over allocated memory? I'm not so good at assembly to figure that out. But isn't it before the data? That's not what I really want but it's okay. And what if eg. memory till 511 is allocated, then won't `alignas (512) struct Foo f;` just allocate memory from 512 to 516? No over allocation? I am sure I am wrong and I hope a lot that you say it's wrong.